# Deploying Django on an apache server

Tags: python, django, deployment, mod-wsgi

I am new to web development. So be gentle. AND thanks in advance.
I am developing on windows env. and deploying on a linux server w/ Python 2.6.2 installed.
Running apache2.2 as Virtual Host, and I am using mod_wsgi. I plan to serve media files from the same Virtual Host.

I have a django site and I am now ready to deploy. I am stuck, and every site I go to seems to be outdated/incomplete/overmyhead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/

...only 2 links as for the newbness

The top link seems to be what I need yet I am still confused on these things:

1. What does the file structure look like on the server

   - I cannot change/edit server files myself, I rely on the dba for that
   - I have django.wsgi, and django.wsgi~, where do those go?
   - Where do I put my project in relation to those wsgi files?
2. The httpd.conf file is something that the server has on it? or do I create another?
3. Do I need to put django in any way shape or form on the server? If so where? And what about the packages like registration, defaults?

Again sorry for the newbness, I have been banging my head for 2 weeks on this.
Any help/links will be greatly appreciated unless they link me to the django-docs. I have read those...A LOT! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also go read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

and watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

The latter includes Django examples and talks a bit about locations, permissions etc.

The first of these is even linked to in the document in the Django documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I have been looking for.
One thing though, I am still not sure about one thing; I am used to working on local machine and every bit of django is on the python path. Then I need to put this on a server that is running our intranet. Will that server's python installation need django and other third party packages within the site-packages directory, or do I put it on my allotted server space? If the ladder, how do I point that to python. And again thank you for your patience and support.

Comment: Apache is going to run your code from a directory, but it's going to use the python interpreter that's on the whole server. So, simply install Django and your 3rd-party packages, and it will take care of all the paths itself.

Comment: So you are saying yes it does need to be installed on the server itself? The reason I ask is because I have been getting loads of mixed responses on this. I only access the server through filezilla. So if it NEEDS to be on the server I will have to put in a request for that. But if I can put it on the server through filezilla I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: Go read up about Python virtual environments. Use these instead of installing into system wide Python. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Comment: In the second link of your post all I had to do was view your slideshow presentation and it had everything I needed. I am sorry I was too hasty in my first comment. I skimmed through the slides and thought you were talking about virtual host rather than virtual environments. I am fairly confident I can get this up, as soon as I show the admin how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

1. It doesn't matter where the files go. They just have to be readable/executable by the user that the web server is running under.
   I don't know what you mean by `django.wsgi~`, that sounds like a backup file created by your editor - you don't need that.
2. Yes the httpd.conf is the configuration file for Apache. Some distributions (eg Debian and Ubuntu) split this up into separate files for each site that the server runs. If your administrator is the only one who can edit files, he will know about this already.
3. Yes, you need Django, and any third-party packages.

Comment: 1. the django.wsgi~ is gone
2. I have space on the server to work with, I can edit those files.
Where I add all the projects files and the django.wsgi file. The mod_wsgi I don't have access to. Do I need to make a seperate file and add what is explained here?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/
3.Do those files need to be on the server's installation of python in the site packages or do I put them somewhere else? if so where?

Answer (score 1):

@Nathan

An easier option for you while you are learning this is not to really have to many expenses.

I could also suggest you take a look at Heroku - allows you to easily deploy your applications in minutes.

Up until recently they only supported RoR and they have brought in support for Django and Python - they have some really well documented tutorials as well.

I hope this helps

[Heroku Django / Python tutorial](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django)

Comment: While I do appreciate your advice, it is very important I learn this.

Comment: of course - I wrote a small tutorial few months ago, since I had the same questions and wanted to know more and more and more... so I will go ahead and paste this for you as well as reference material - it explains a bit more about httpd, mod_wsgi, going through the whole server setup etc. - http://bit.ly/pQirM5

Comment: Thank you for this. This is a lot of content and seems to be what I need.

Comment: @Nathan - Great! Feel free to post a comment on their if you have any questions too, i'd love to answer them

Answer (score 1):

I have written up an simple deployment guide for django applications it can be found [here](http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/10190888471/ultimate-django-deployment-tutorial). It goes all the way from project setup and deployment. I also have references setup. I honestly believe it answers all your questions, I would give it a look.

Goodluck.